# How to maintain session in Wpf Application between two window?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, data-binding

I have `WPF` Application where I have one Registration window.
when I click on registration tab it open registration window.
My requirement is that if there is no activity after clicking on registration tab it should timed out and move to a different window.

Comment: Can you please post what you tried sofar?

Comment: Good pattern is to retain one window throughout application. WPF exposes ContentControl in order to swich between views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to check the Idle time on the window

on the windows loaded event

```
 private static DispatcherTimer idleTimer;
 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            idleTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            idleTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            idleTimer.Tick += this.OnTimerTick;
            idleTimer.Start();
        }
```

Timer Tick Event

```
private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    uint idleTime = this.GetIdleTime();
    if (idleTime > 5000)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Idle Time Helper Method

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO dummy);


private uint GetIdleTime()
{
    LASTINPUTINFO lastUserAction = new LASTINPUTINFO();
    lastUserAction.CbSize = (uint)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(lastUserAction);
    GetLastInputInfo(ref lastUserAction);
    return (uint)Environment.TickCount - lastUserAction.DwTime;
}   

internal struct LASTINPUTINFO
{        
    public uint CbSize;   
    public uint DwTime;   

}
```

Comment: Hi Justin, Thanks for your Response Can you tell me how to track user last activity?

Comment: Trying to track button clicked or something like that on a window?

Comment: it's on window_loaded event. i want to track user last activity.

Comment: I don't get you exactly.. I think user last activity means ;if the user click on a button ,or enter in a textbox ?

Comment: Actually helper method works well. It solves my problem.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can put values in `Application.Current.Properties` to use it across application.

```
Application.Current.Resources["ResourceName"] = "SomeData";
```

> The general strategy for storing such data is to have public classes
>   with public properties/fields and access them from anywhere in the
>   application. However, with Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF), the
>   framework itself provides an application-wide “storage bag”,
>   Application.Properties, that could be used for the very same purpose.
>   This bag is an app-domain specific thread-safe key-value based
>   IDictionary instance.

Comment: But it's not solving question's problem that contains periodical checking user (last) activity.

Comment: First thing his question doesn't contain any code. I can not write whole code for him. I'm guiding him to start with this

Comment: Hi Rahul thanks for your response. can you tell how to check user last activity?